# Reach pivot table fields Laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I created 3 tables :

```
categories
    id
    admin_id
    created_at
    updated_at
    deleted_at

langs
    id
    langname_fr
    langname
    ....
```

And a pivot table with fields i could fill :

```
category_lang
    lang_id
    category_id
    catname
    catshortname
    ....
```

In a controller i created a method index() :

```
public function index()
{
    $categories = Category::with('langs')->get();
    $categoriesCount = Sector::count();
    return view('admin.pages.maps.index', compact('categories', 'categoriesCount'));
}
```

Now i would like to "reach" the fields in the pivot table ... for example how can i display "catname" in my view ?

Here is my model (Category model) :

```
public function langs() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Lang')
        ->withPivot(
            'sectname',
            'sectshortname',
            'sectdescription',
            'sectshortdescription',
            'created_at',
            'updated_at',
            'deleted_at'
        );
}
```

In the view :

```
@foreach($categories as $category)
        <pre>
            {{ var_dump($category->pivot->catname) }}
        </pre>
@endforeach
```

it returns : Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: Post your models too

Comment: Use documentation as much as possible. You need to use [`withPivot()` on relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships) - use SUPER+f to search term withPivot and you will get what you want.

Comment: I created the method in my model where i used withPivot ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use another foreach loop to retrieve langs with pivot data,

```
@foreach($categories as $category)
        @foreach($category->langs as $lang)        
            {{ $lang->pivot->sectname }}
        @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: @davidvera at the end, all developers have the same mind :)  you can upvote also as an appreciation.

Answer (score 1):

You can sipmly add `->pivot` keyword like this :

```
@foreach($categories as $category)
    @foreach($category->langs as $lang)
        <pre>
            {{ var_dump($lang->pivot->catname) }}
        </pre>
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: I tried it ... i updated my question ... i receive an error

Answer (score 1):

In `Category` model:

```
public function langs()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class)->withPivot('catname');
}
```

Now you can retrieve data like...

```
$categories->langs->pivot->catname
```

---

Ref: [Laravel's Eloquent: Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships)

A good article: [Pivot tables and many-to-many relationships](http://laraveldaily.com/pivot-tables-and-many-to-many-relationships/)

Answer (score 0):

Thank to all answers i finally found :

```
@foreach($categories as $category)
    @foreach($category->langs as $translation)
        <pre>
            {{ dd($translation->pivot->sectname) }}
        </pre>
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```